# Why can't a built-in function be overridden in Rebol?

Tags: rebol, rebol2

I have created this

```
cloneset: :set
set: func[word [word!] value][
if/else (type? get word) = list! [
    print "list is immutable"
][

    cloneset word value
    protect word
]
]
protect 'cloneset
protect 'set
```

I have this error when defining the val function with the new set function:

```
val: func[word [word!] value][
    set word value
    protect word
    value
]

>> val: func[word [word!] value][
[        set word value
[        protect word
[        value
[    ]
** Script Error: set has no refinement called any
** Where: throw-on-error
** Near: if error? set/any 'blk try
```

I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 6):

When you redefine a word that's defined in `system/words`, you should redefine it *exactly*. The `set` word has two refinements: `/pad` and `/any` that your redefinition should also include:

```
cloneset: :set
set: func [
    word [word! block!]
    value
    /any
    /pad
][
    either all [word? word list? get word] [
        throw make error! "List is immutable!"
    ][
        comment {
           At this point you'll have to forward the arguments and refinements
           of your SET method to CLONESET. This will be made much easier in R3
           with the new APPLY function.
        }
    ]
]
```

(I have not tested the above code at all. It should be regarded as pseudocode.)

Comment: Have voted up for you on multiple posts, but cannot mark good answer as I wasn't registered.

Answer (score 3):

To be sure to get the spec right, you can reuse the spec of the original function:

```
set: func spec-of :cloneset [
    'new-implementation
]

source set
set: func [
    {Sets a word, block of words, or object to specified value(s).} 
    word [any-word! block! object!] "Word or words to set" 
    value [any-type!] "Value or block of values" 
    /any "Allows setting words to any value." 
    /pad {For objects, if block is too short, remaining words are set to NONE.}
]['new-implementation]
```

in older versions without 'spec-of, you can use 'first in its place.

Answer (score 3):

In Rebol any built-in function can be overridden. You actually did override the `set` function above.

However, when seeing the error you obtained you should have examined the `throw-on-error` function. You would have found out that in the function source code there is a call of the `set` function looking as follows:

```
set/any 'blk try ...
```

This call suggests that the `throw-on-error` function assumes the `set` variable to refer to a function having a `/any` refinement. Since your redefined version of the function does not have such a refinement, the `throw-on-error` function cannot call it that way and thus the error you obtained.

Generally spoken, you can redefine anything, but you have to take the responsibility for the redefinition, especially if the redefined version is not backwards compatible with the original.

Comment: also, note that even if you redefine a function or value, an old reference to it can still exist within earlier code, look at this topic for more on this and some related learning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592072/how-to-capture-words-bound-in-outer-context-when-creating-new-context